# GWOffice wont install

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, deb

Does anyone have GWOffice working?

I can't seem to get

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tombeckmann/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gwoffice
```

Working. It seems there isn't any package with that name.

If somebody could give me a link to the debs I need or point me to a repo that holds the package that'd be awesome.

Comment: It would help if you put in the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Your tag indicate that you're using Ubuntu 14.04, that's [called Trusty Tahr](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames). As you can see from the package list on the [the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~tombeckmann/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), there is no version of GWOffice packaged for Trusty Tahr. The highest version that a package is currently available for is 12.04, which is a shame IMHO.

Comment: is there any way to force this install, and install any required libraries from Tahr into Yakkety Yak?

Comment: It was such a useful tool.